# How to effectively deal with large datasets in Core Data?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using core data in my app to store entities that could have as many as 50k objects or more. I have this paired to an NSFetchedResultsController in a table view. The table view works fine due to cell reuse however my biggest problem is queuring the actual database to get the dataset.

When i first load the table view i need all results from the db. I am using the default fetch request with a single sort descriptor and I have set the batchSize to 1,000. On an iPad 2 this query takes up to **15 secs** to finish! I also have to run this query after a search has been cancelled so overall it makes the app unusable. My assumption is that CD still has to resolve all those results or setup the sections or something, i really have no idea but just using the batchSize doesn't help?? The content is also very dynamic in the sense that new rows are always getting added, sort order changing etc.. so caching has a limited benefit.

I am thinking now that the best option would be to use a fetchLimit in the fetchRequest and then implement some basic paging. When the table view scrolls to the end fetch the next "page" of results? My only problem with this approach is that i lose the sectionIndex and i cant think of any way around that.

Anyone have any ideas or dealt with this issue already?

Comment: Why do you need the whole data set??

Answer (score 4):

When you set the fetch request for the FRC the batch size should be just a few items bigger than, maybe twice the size as, the number of items that can be seen on screen at any one time. The FRC already does the pagination for you you just need to set the page size better.

Comment: thx i understand how batch size works however my problem is the actual sql query which takes forever.

Comment: But why do you need to make such a big request?

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately thats the way the product is designed. I guess its not unlike any other app that has a large number of rows but gets around this by only showing x number of results per page. The only way to emulate this is to use a fetchLimit to stop Core Data from getting more data then necessary. The data also doesnt lend itself to a consistent grouping that i could use to narrow down the result set.

Answer (score 2):

s.newave,

Do your rows have variable height? If so, then the table view asks you to calculate each height and that causes every row to be fetched. 15 seconds is not an unreasonable time to fetch 50K items.

The bigger problem is your statement about not wanting to change your design. Frankly, a 50K item tableview is useless. You should change your design -- not because CD is slow, it isn't -- but because your design is not pragmatically usable.

Andrew

P.S. The fetched results controller is designed for mainstream applications. a 50K table view is not a mainstream app. If you insist on keeping with a 50K table view design, you will have to make your own controller.